# How can I delete window action in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have created one module in that I have added window action and now in another module I would like to remove that window action. Is there any way to remove / Hide window action ?

Let say following is the action available in sale base module and I would like to remove it in my custom module.

```xml
    <record id="action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Invoice Order</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">sale.advance.payment.inv</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
    </record>

    <!-- TODO: check if we need this -->
    <record model="ir.values" id="sale_order_line_make_invoice">
        <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line" />
        <field name="name">Invoice Orders</field>
        <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
        <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_view_sale_advance_payment_inv'))" />
        <field name="key">action</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    </record>
```

[image]

Comment: Most easy way is to remove it using js. When I was beginner I've used js, but now there should be more professional way to achieve this. I'll search it for you

Comment: What if you unlink this action_multi record?

Comment: Anyhow that record must be deleted while the module installation then it's fine for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested and it works. You just need to delete this `ir.value` record

```
self.env.ref('sale.sale_order_line_make_invoice').unlink()
```

and dropdown is empty

[image]

To make it happen automatically you need to make this changes:

create xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <function model="*model_name*" name="_test_function"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

create model with this function

```
@api.model
def _test_function(self):
    self.env.ref('sale.sale_order_line_make_invoice').unlink()
```

Good Luck

Comment: @Dachi: What happens after second update on the deleting module? Does that update gets finished (without blocking error)? I'am asking because i really don't know. I just know, that my solutions should raise errors in log, but the update should run through.

Comment: We can test first if record exists and then delete it, I have not tested it for errors yet because I've not such task now, but the code I wrote is working as I've tested for first run. Nice question tho

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the `ir.values` record, which is "creating" this action. There are 2 (and some more ofcourse) possibilities to do that.

1. Deleting by using xml/external ID

   Condition: The `ir.values` record have to have an external ID. The deleting module needs the other one as dependency.

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <delete model="ir.values" id="my_module.my_ir_values_id" />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

2. Deleting by searching

   Condition: You need something to search the record for example the name.

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <delete model="ir.values" search="[('name', '=', 'Invoice Order')]" />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Upvoted. Nice answer, but I prefer python side for this kind of jobs. I'm very back-end guy :D. But as you asked in my answer does this produce erros? Your first example will raise error imho

Comment: It should raise errors in the log, but the module update process should run through. I've used this methods for like 3 years in odoo 7-10.

Comment: So better version is to check if record exists and then delete it safely, your second example will work very well I think. But first example is bad code for me, hate when errors or warnings occur